# Memory leak in object

Tags: objective-c

I am getting the memory leak in my objects setters can any one help me to resolve this??

Code:

```
  - (void)setEstimateTax2Type:(NSString *)aEstimateTax2Type
{

if ((!estimateTax2Type && !aEstimateTax2Type) || (estimateTax2Type && aEstimateTax2Type && [estimateTax2Type isEqualToString:aEstimateTax2Type])) return;

[estimateTax2Type release];
estimateTax2Type = [aEstimateTax2Type copy]  ;
}
```

Thank's in advance.

Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional:

```
if (
  (!estimateTax2Type && !aEstimateTax2Type) || 
  (estimateTax2Type && aEstimateTax2Type && 
    [estimateTax2Type isEqualToString:aEstimateTax2Type])
) return;
```

Appears to terminate the function before releasing the memory:

```
[estimateTax2Type release];
```

Although I don't see any `alloc`

Comment: The conditional terminates the method only when both objects are nil or equal.  So it should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the setter correct (for example your condition is entirely unnecessary):

```
//.h
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *estimateTax2Type;
//.m
@synthesize estimateTax2Type;
```

Comment: note that with this you still need to implement dealloc and release estimateTax2Type

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with sending messages to nil.  So your test can be:

```
if ([aEstimateTax2Type isEqualToString: estimateTax2Type])
{
    return;
}
```

However, that's not the cause of your leak.  I suspect, you are not releasing estimateTax2Type in your dealloc method.

Answer (score 1):

do you have a dealloc method to release `estimateTax2Type` when you're class is dealloced?

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [estimateTax2Type release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thank's for all for your valuable suggestions.